# C++ Calculator using Stacks and Queues

Tags: c++, stack, queue, calculator, postfix-notation

I'm trying to understand a topic in class about using stacks and queues as a means of programming a calculator. I understand what infix and postfix expression is but how does it make it easier for a program to evaluate an expression and why are queues and stacks ideal in this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It makes the order of operations simpler to handle, for example:

```
+ * - 4 2 5 3
```

Can only mean

```
((4 - 2) * 5) + 3
```

Which might be more readable for us, but we need to know the order of operations and match parentheses to figure it out.

As for implementing: if you had a stack, you could handle the expression above as follows:

1. Read `+` (an operation), push it onto the stack,
2. Read `*` (an operation), push it onto the stack,
3. Read `-` (an operation), push it onto the stack,
4. Read `4` (a number), the top of the stack is not a number, so push it onto the stack.
5. Read `2` (a number), the top of the stack is a number, so pop from the stack twice, you get `4 - 2`, calculate it (`2`), and push the result (`2`) onto the stack.
6. Read `5` (a number), the top of the stack is a number, so pop from the stack twice, you get `2 * 5`, push the result (`10`) onto the stack.
7. Read `3` (a number), the top of the stack is a number, so pop from the stack twice, you get `3 + 10`, push the result (`13`) onto the stack.
8. Nothing left to read, pop from the stack and return the result (`13`).

So as you can see, the expression was evaluated using a few simple rules and without having to search through the entire string for parentheses or having to decide whether multiplication has priority over addition and subtraction.