# Calculator with bracket in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I'm implementing a calculator in C ++ that respects the priorities of parentheses. I am trying to use `std :: string :: find_last_of` to find the last occurrence of `(` and `std :: string :: find` to find the first occurrence of `)`. Once that is done, I reckon the content of the extracted substring and continuing with the rest of the string.
For example:

```
1 + 1 * (9 * (11-1 + 2))
```

I find the last occurrence of `(`, the first of `)` and calculating `11-1 + 2`. And so it continues.
Is this the right approach to this problem or is there something better?
Thank you.

Comment: [What about `(1+1)*(2+2)`?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

Comment: the priority is the same so it is irrelevant, right?

Comment: The best way is to use a stack!

Comment: @LucaPizzamiglio do you have some example?

Comment: @LocalHero [here](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/5/) you can find a pdf explaining how to use queues and stacks. Stack can be used to evaluate the correctness and the value of this type of expressions

Comment: You need to think about precedence rules too... What about `1+2*3` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the standard approaches to this problem consists of 2 steps:

1) Convert your expression to Reverse Polish notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation using Shunting-yard algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

2) Evaluate converted expression using stack.

The another way to do this:

1) Easy step: Write Backus–Naur Form of your expressions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

And after you have 2 options:

2a) Build Finite-State Machine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine (exists a lot of tools to do this: ANTLR, ...).

2b) Recursive descent method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Answer (score 3):

You can use Reversed Polish Notation:
You will need to convert the expression into reversed polish notation and then implement a stack based algorithm to pop and push to the final answer.

Have a look at the Shunting- Yard algorithm here: To convert the expression into RPN.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Also Have a look at
[Writing a simple equation parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582398/writing-a-simple-equation-parser)
For help to implement the stack, have a look here:
[C++ Calculator using Stacks and Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552284/c-calculator-using-stacks-and-queues)